# Megento MIGS (Merchant-Hosted Payment Request) integration error payment server system error - 15433-08031820 invalid permission : moto

Tags: magento, integration, mastercard

I am trying to integrate MIGS(Merchant-Hosted Payment Request gateway) in magento and am getting following error

```
payment server system error - 15433-08031820 invalid permission : moto
```

Am sending the request with following parameter order ,

```
vpc_AccessCode=5F98F927&vpc_Amount=50&vpc_CardExp=1705&vpc_CardNum=4005550000000001&vpc_CardSecurityCode=123&vpc_CardType=VI&vpc_Command=pay&vpc_MerchTxnRef=2000664421&vpc_Merchant=TEST803684000&vpc_OrderInfo=2000664421&vpc_ReturnURL=http%253A%252F%252Fstaging.hitthedeals.com%252Fdubai%252Fmigsvpc%252Fmerchant%252Fresponse%252F&vpc_Version=1&vpc_SecureHash=98FBA60138424BB0FE670E27B367A84B
```

And am getting following response with **vpc_TxnResponseCode=7**

```
vpc_Amount=50&vpc_BatchNo=0&vpc_Command=pay&vpc_Locale=en_AE&vpc_MerchTxnRef=2000664421&vpc_Merchant=TEST803684000&vpc_Message=I5433-08052003%3A+Invalid+Permission+%3A+moto&vpc_OrderInfo=2000664421&vpc_SecureHash=2920F4E131824EA3ED4CFEAA48D7BE79&vpc_TransactionNo=0&vpc_TxnResponseCode=7&vpc_Version=1
```

[image]
Can anybody please help to solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

You need to have MOTO permission setup in your MiGS account, if not it won't work. Ask your bank

Answer (score 0):

Click on the `Manage Merchants - Merchant Summary` inside Migs MM portal.

[image: Payment Details Edit]

Click `EDIT`

Choose MOTO also (Check it)
[image]